# Define as int already but still determine as NoneType

Tags: python

I got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Owen/Desktop/Python/BlackJack.py", line 281, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:/Users/Owen/Desktop/Python/BlackJack.py", line 230, in main
    while money > 0:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

But I have already defined the variable as int

```
def main():
    money = int(1000)
    while money > 0:
        if len(cards) <= 13:
            print("No Card")
            print("Money:", money, " Bet: 100\n")
            exit()
        else:
            print(len(cards))
```

Why the system still determine "money" as NoneType? Thank you.

Comment: add full script

Comment: Where is `cards`?

Comment: yes, you can replace real cards and how you're run it

Comment: What's the point of `int(1000)`?

Answer (score 2):

The variable `money` given by you is already an integer and hence there is no need to write `int(1000)`. Next thing is inside the `while` loop you are nowhere incrementing or decrementing the money variable and hence the while condition `while money > 0:` is always true which will make an endless loop. Inside the if condition you have kept an `exit()` so that after first entry inside the if condition it will break the loop whereas if it comes to else part every time, the loop wont stop as money = 1000 is always greater than 0.
Please verify if that loop is needed as per requirements.